# Flexslider won't work with WordPress' jQuery | Dependencies

Tags: jquery, slideshow, wp-dependencies

When I try to use the Flexslider with 'built-in' jquery, the Flexslider won't work. When I use my own **myjquery** file, It works as if nothing ever.
Do I always have to use my own jquery file even wordpress has its own?

- Wordpress' (built in) jQuery vserion: 1.11.3
- Flexbox required jQuery version: 1.7+
- **myjquery** = jquery version: 1.12.0

Summary: flexbox should work with jQuery of WordPress.

---

#### More Details

Flexslider doesn't work when I use Wordpress' jQuery.
It works when I add my own **myjquery.js** which is jquery 1.12.0 and when I dequeue original jquery `wp_dequeue_script('jquery');`.
It looks like WordPress' jQuery is not visible for my Flexslider and custom.js file.

Errors:
When I run the site with WordPress with its own jQuery there is one error:
`$ is not a function` file: 'custom.js:2:1' what means that jquery is not found but it's included in header (I've checked). My conclusion is the dependency `array('jquery')` doesn't work. I've tried to use `wp_register_script('flexbox', ...)` with different function (even without dependencies and false, false or true, true, etc..)

*When I use 'myjquery' there is no errors and plugin works correctly.*

The content of 'custom.js':

`$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});`

---

Register and include styles & scripts (part of the **functions.php** file):

```
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js' );
wp_register_script( 'myjquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js' );
wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flexslider.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('flexslider'), false, true );

// Enqueue :: styles & scripts
function mytheme_enqueue_items() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-main-css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-responsive' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider-css' );

  // wp_enqueue_script( '**myjquery**' ); // **flexslider works correctly when uncommented**
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_items' );
```

Comment: Why your register scripts are outside the function?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using for `myjquery` (that flexslider works with)? It could work with the version you've tested with but not with the version that is included in WordPress. Further, what actually happens when it "won't work?" Are there errors in the console?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam to get possibilities to use them for other functions not just for this one. It's not wrong practice and doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @megmorsie I've just updated description in my post.

Comment: It is not a very bright/smart idea to run your code outside a function, or hook as in this case. Plugins and child themes can't remove them, and I believe all of that code runs completely out of context. Creating `<link>` tags outside the `<head>` tags is invalid HTML, which is not `W3C` complient (*all websites must comply*)

Comment: @PieterGoosen No one `<link>` is outside of the `<head>`. As I mentioned above, I've tested `wp_register_script(...)` with different arguments. Until I use **my own** jquery file called 'myjquery' the Flexslider is not visible and I have an error `$ is not a function` for file `custom.js:2:1`. By the way, this topic is about dependencies not good practices but I'm trying to use official WordPress documentation correctly.

Comment: *$ is not a function*  is something that was handled many times on this stack. You have a jquery conflict. All custom scripts should be running in no-conflict mode

Comment: Thanks for thint. I found a topic about [jquery conflicts](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/jquery-conflict-8) instantly. It's about using `jQuery(...)` instead `$` sign and everything works correctly. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was jquery conflict (error `$ is not a function`).
All custom scripts should be running in no-conflict mode.
I've used `jQuery(...)` instead of `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be registering your scripts in the same function that you enqueue them with.

Your comment `flexslider works correctly when uncommented` suggests that you might just be missing this:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`

Though jQuery is "built-in," you still need to enqueue the script with the handle. Basically, WordPress includes the files and does the `wp_register_script` part, but you still need to enqueue it, which tells WordPress you want to load it.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I just noticed that you have jQuery as a dependency in your `wp_register_script`. So you shouldn't need to enqueue it like I suggested above.

Comment: I've doubt that dependency doesn't work but it should, because version of jQuery of WordPress core is 1.11.3, the Flexslider requires 1.7+. I've tried to use `wp_register_script('flexslider', ...)` with different arguments. When I try to use the above code (without myjquery) debugger notices error: `$ is not a function :: file 'custom.js'`  
The `custom.js` file is flexslider's start script. This means that the jquery library is not used but it's included in header (I've checked).

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! :)